# Adding second ArcGIS Online Basemap to ArcGIS Pro Map?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online-basemaps

In ArcGIS Pro 2.3.0 I would like to be able to switch ArcGIS Online Basemaps at a particular scale.  This should be easy to do by using complementary Visibility Ranges on two basemap layers in the Contents pane.

However, if I use the Basemap button to access the Basemap gallery, and choose another basemap, the one I choose replaces the original.

How can I add a second ArcGIS Online Basemap to an ArcGIS Pro Map?

Comment: Multiple maps with zoom lock (or whatever it's called)?

Comment: @Midavalo I think you may be thinking of [Link multiple views](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/link-multiple-views.htm).  If so, that's not it because I'm only working within a single Map view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At GeoNet I found a [solution from rleclair-esristaff](https://community.esri.com/thread/184380-basemap-scale-changes#comment-640723) which was written for an earlier version of ArcGIS Pro:

> In Pro, it will "update basemap."  To get around this, go to the
>   Project Pane, click Portal, click the cloud icon and search for a new
>   basemap - USA_Topo_Maps for example and add it to the current map. 
>   Now you have two basemaps.

I have been able to adapt this to ArcGIS Pro 2.3.0 but at this more recent version the process to add OpenStreetMap as a second basemap involves more steps:

1. In the Catalog (formerly known as Project) pane click the Portal tab
2. Click the Groups button
3. Search for OpenStreetMap
4. One of the groups returned is called ArcGIS Online Basemaps so double-click that to see what is in it
5. OpenStreetMap is there so right-click on it to Add And Open
6. A new map named OpenStreetMap is added to the project
7. Use the Contents pane to right-click on the OpenStreetMap layer to Copy it
8. Switch to the Map that needs OpenStreetMap as a second basemap and click on it in the Contents pane to Paste the layer
9. For tidiness use the Catalog pane and its Project tab to expand the Maps node and right-click on OpenStreetMap to Delete it.